# Debug logs not working for salesforce sites with webservice class

Tags: webservices, force.com-sites

How to set the debug logs for the Force.com Site data in new winter release. Because initially it was working few days back but not working now.

I am getting the data on the site from the external source but the logs are not getting generated.

Please help.

Comment: [You now have to set a cookie](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_debugging_guest_user.htm)

Comment: When i hit the URL for the site in that case the logs are getting generated. But when the data came up on the site from the external source in that case the logs are not getting generated.

Comment: @AbhinavBhatia - Unless that external source has their own cookie set you won't get the logs. At least you got it to work internally. no dice for me yet.

Comment: But how to set the cookie for the external source, because i am getting the response from the 3rd party on the site and through the site i am consuming that. So how to set the cookie for the external source?

Comment: No cookie, no debug logs.

Comment: Yes, still not getting any logs when the site is hit from the external source. No logs are getting generated.

Comment: How to set the debug logs for the Force.com Site data in new winter release. Because initially it was working few days back but not working now.

I am getting the data on the site from the external source but the logs are not getting generated.